# mock moment.js in node using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, momentjs

I'm trying to mock `moment.js` in order to predict my integration tests.
I've been trying to mock `jest` like [this](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/mocking-moment-js-in-jest-a-simple-one-line-solution-61259ffaaa2):

```
import moment from 'moment'
...
jest.mock('moment', () => () => ({valueOf: () => 100})
```

But when I run my test, the source code uses the normal `moment`.

I have succeeded in overriding `moment` behavior by doing [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/), but it is not good enough as it override more functions which I don't want to change.

Answer (score 0):

when I have to mock a `moment.js` function, I do it using `stubs` from `Sinon.js` (https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.7/stubs/).

It goes basically like this:

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon'
import moment from 'moment'
...
const stubValueOf = sinon.stub(moment, 'valueOf');
stubValueOf.returns(100);
```

**Important:** a good practice using stubs is only use it for a specific test and not the whole test file. So, after every time you use it, use `stubValueOf.restore()`. If you want to 'stub' the method with different values in the same test, use `stubValueOf.reset()`.